# How do I wait for a certain function to finish before executing another one?

Tags: javascript

I want to start out by saying I have found other similar question, but I don't understand how to execute with with my code as it isn't a function I created myself.

I have the following code:

```
$("#dataset").load('/hemaexplorerbeta/php/getDataset.php');
```

This loads some data and puts in in a dropdown.

Afterwards I'm calling the following to see if it's loaded when I need the list:

```
document.getElementById('dataset').value
```

Bot of these are in my document on load, and I need them to be. How can I make sure to get a value from "#dataset" AFTER the data has been downloaded? Yes, the data is fetched from a MySQL database.

Comment: y would u tag as mysql?

Comment: lol, this is not mysql man, this is javascript/Jquery

Comment: Yeah I just quickly posted the thing, my bad.. O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass function as second parameter.
Example:

```
$("#dataset").load('/hemaexplorerbeta/php/getDataset.php', function() {
  var x = document.getElementById('dataset').value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback function for .load:

```
$("#dataset").load('/hemaexplorerbeta/php/getDataset.php', function() {
    // This gets executed when the content is loaded
    $(this).show();
});
```